# Using OLEDB to access Excel, can't pattern match in query

Tags: sql, excel, vb6

### Context

I'm writing a program in Visual Basic to help automate data entry and make things easier overall. The data is kept in Excel spreadsheets, and I'd like to keep them the way they are, but import data to my program's `DataGridView`. Along with importing data to my program's view, I like to search for specific things in specific columns (filtering). At the moment my method of doing this is to send query through OLEDB for what I want, and display results. For the most part, everything is working fine.

### What isn't working fine:

For some reason, it takes my `LIKE` queries literally. If I put into the OleDbCommand one of the following queries (pretend sheet and column are correct)

```
SELECT * FROM [sheet$] WHERE [column] LIKE '.House.'

SELECT * FROM [sheet$] WHERE [column] LIKE '.*House.*'
```

I get back records where the column literally had .House. or .* House.* instead of all records where the column has a string containing House somewhere in it.

### The Big Question

Is it possible to pattern match when querying Excel with OLEDB? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not (and even if so...) is there an overall better way to be doing what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: SQL uses %, not .* for match any.

Comment: Holy crap am I ever dumb. Thank you very much lol. I think I'll delete this account I just made and go cry in a corner now -_-

Is there a way to upvote you, or say it solved it?

Comment: I upvoted him for you.  :)  OLE DB consumers (such as ADO) and providers use the %, but keep in mind that the older DAO using Access or Excel uses the *.  That's probably where you got mixed up.